# Preventing client side abuse/cheating of repeating Ajax call that rewards users

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a coin program to award the members for being on my site. The program I have makes two random numbers and compares them, if they are the same, you get a coin. The problem I have is someone could go in the console and get "free" coins. They could also cheat by opening more tabs or making a program to generate more coins right now which I am trying to stop. I am thinking about converting it over to php from js to stop the cheating (for the most part) but I don't know how to do this. The code in question is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/version2.0/coin/coins.php',
    data: {Cid : cs, mode : 'updateCoins'},
    success: function (msg) {
        window.msg=msg;
    }});
```

And the code for the console is that with a loop around it. In the code above, "cs" is the id of the member so by replacing it with their id would cause them to get all the coins they would want.

Should I just have an include with variable above it? But then how would I display the success message which has the current number of coins. Also, this code is in a setInterval function that repeats every 15 milliseconds.

Comment: Why not time stamp the updates? One update  per X-amount of hours/days. If the user attempts to trick the system and submit more coins you can check the last update and reject it if the update is too soon/close to the previous update. (Assuming you're saving the coins/updates server-side) Also generating the random numbers server-side would be best as the numbers can't be changed.

Comment: I have a timestamp right now to help me look for  the cheaters, how soon is too soon to you think? Everything is saved on server-side.

Comment: That depends how often you want to allow them to run this coin application. If it's a gift then it's a choice of your own.  My personal input isn't valid since i  know nothing about your website. Could be once an hour or once every six hours but i would recommend generating the random numbers server-side and comparing the last current time with the time stamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways you could do this, but perhaps the simplest would be to go in your server side code - when a request comes in, you check the time of last coin update, if there ins't one, you run your coin code and save the time of this operation in their session. If there is a stored time, ensure that it is beyond the desired time. If it is, continue to the coin update. If it isn't, simply respond with a 403 or other failure code.

In pseudo code:

```
if (!$userSession['lastCoinTime'] || $currentTime + $delay > $userSession['lastCoinTime']) {
  // coin stuff
  $userSession['lastCoinTime'] = // new time
} else {
  // don't give them a chance at coin, respond however you want
}
```

However, since you're talking about doing this check every 15ms, I would use websockets so that the connection to the server is ongoing. Either way, the logic can be comparable.

Just in case there's any uncertainty about this, definitely do ALL of the coin logic on the server. You can never trust the user for valid data coming in. The most you can trust, depending on how your authentication is setup, is some kind of secret code only they would have that would just let you know who they are, which is a technique used in place of persistent sessions. Unless you're doing that, you would rely on the session to know who the user is - definitely don't let them tell you that either!